# Trigger.io browser extension: how to generate exclude_matches in the chrome manifest?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, trigger.io

For the browser extension we're building, we need to be able to generate an 'exclude_matches' field in Chrome's manifest (and ideally for all the other browsers as well). I can manually edit the generate manifest file, but it'll of course be over-written anytime the extension is rebuilt.

Comment: 1. _(and ideally for all the other browsers as well)_ - how do you imagine other browser using Chrome Extension manifest?

Comment: 2. _I can manually edit the generate manifest file, but it'll of course be over-written anytime the extension is rebuilt._ - from this statement it seems, that you are already able to generate manifest file. So what is your question about?

Comment: The goal is to have the trigger.io config.json generate proper plugins for all browsers. Part of 'proper' in this case means having an 'exclude_matches' entry to control where _not_ to load certain content-scripts.

Comment: I can generate a Chrome extension, which includes a manifest file, using forge, but there's no way to have it generate the 'exclude_matches' entry on every build.

Comment: @sgrove must you use 'excludes_matches' in the config? Instead you could add a check in your content script and have it not execute further if it detects it is on a page that is excluded. Could that approach work?